Convergence of SGD for least squares
Given $X\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $y\in\mathbb R^m$, we want to solve the least squares (LS) problem $$f(\theta)=\min_{\theta\in\mathbb R^n}\frac12||X\theta-y||^2.$$
This problem can be expressed in stochastic gradient descent (SGD) form by writing the objective function as $$f(\theta)=\sum_{i=1}^mf_i(\theta),$$ where $f_i(\theta)=\frac12(x_i^T\theta-y_i)^2$ with $x_i^T$ being the $i$-th row of $X$.
The update is $$\theta_{k+1}=\theta_k-\eta_k\nabla f_{i_k}(\theta_k),$$ where $\eta_k$ is the stepsize and $i_k\sim\text{Unif}([m])$.
Question: When the $x_i$'s are orthogonal, show that SGD converges to the LS solution (or in the sense of objective values) with a fixed stepsize.

I am aware of results concerning the convergence of SGD with fixed stepsize for strongly convex objectives (see for instance here). We can verify the second order of the stochastic gradient can be bounded by the gradient of the objective, i.e. $$\mathbb E||\nabla f_{i_k}(\theta_k)||^2\le m\left|\left|\nabla\left(\frac1mf(\theta_k)\right)\right|\right|^2.$$
However, strong convexity seems an issue here. The Hessian of the objective is $\nabla^2 f(\theta)=X^TX$. So for $f$ to be strongly convex, we require $X^TX$ to be positive definite, or equivalently, invertible. But since the rows of $X$ are orthogonal, $\text{rank}(X)=m\le n$. So when $m<n$, $X^TX$ cannot be invertible.

First, you can explicitly write down the updates of SGD in this case to be of the form $\theta_{k+1} = A_k\theta_k + u_k$, with $A_k = I - \eta \,x_{i_k}x_{i_k}^T$ and $u_k = \eta y_{i_k}x_{i_k}$. If you are familiar with linear systems theory, you might have an idea of where I am getting at.
Next step is to note that the LS problem is undertermined, so there are infinitely many solutions. I will consider, as is standard, the minimum-norm solution $\theta^\star = X^T (XX^T)^{-1}y$. Since you assumed orthogonality of the $x_i$'s, this simplifies to $\theta^\star = X^T y$, but you really don't need such assumption, instead it suffices to have linear independence of the $x_i$'s (which is intuitively equivalent to there being no redundant information in your LS problem).
With this and with routine algebraic manipulations, you can rewrite $\theta_{k+1} = A_k\theta_k + u_k$ as simply $\overline{\theta}_{k+1} = A_k\overline{\theta}_k$, where $\overline{\theta}_k = \theta_k - \theta^\star$.
At this stage, assuming always Euclidean norm and induced 2-norm for the sake of simplicity, we can simply note that $\|\overline{\theta}\|_{k+1} \leq \|A_k\|\|\overline{\theta}\|_k$ and
$$\|A_k\| \leq \max_{i=1,\ldots,m}\|I - \eta\, x_i x_i^T\| \leq 1 - \eta \min_{i=1,\ldots,m} \|x_i\|^2 < 1,$$
provided that $\eta > 0$ is small enough.
Therefore, letting $\rho = 1 - \eta \min_{i=1,\ldots,m} \|x_i\|^2$, we have $\|\theta_k - \theta^\star\| \leq \rho^k \|\theta_0 - \theta^\star\|$, which proves a.s. linear convergence of SGD.

There seems to be a mistake in bounding the spectral norm of the $A_k$'s (the second $\le$). Indeed, $A_k$ has eigenvalue 1. Alternatively I can show that the objective value converges to the optimum (which is 0 here).

You're right, I made a mistake. Indeed, there are infinitely many solutions to the problem unless $m=n$, so we can't guarantee convergence towards the minimum-energy one specifically as I suggested. This can be more clearly seen by simply initializing SGD at a solution other than $\theta^\star$, for which we can see that the gradient will be 0, and hence we will not converge to $\theta^\star$. On the other hand, you're right, the objective value should converge to its minimum value almost surely. I don't have a proof or the time to derive one right now, but would be interested in seeing yours.

Ok I ended up taking the time to derive a solution, but I won't post all the details unless you're interested. The short of it is that, unless I made a mistake again, we should have $f(\theta_{k+1})  = f(\theta_k) -2\eta|x_{i_k}|^2\left(1 - \frac{\eta}{2}|x_{i_k}|^2\right) (y_{i_k} - x_{i_k}^T\theta_k)^2$. From here, we can readily conclude a.s. convergence of the objective value.

Thanks. I got the same thing.
